# pandas,read_excel, usecols with list input generating an empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Actually i want to read only a specific column from excel into python dataframe 
my code is

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_excel("3_Plants sorted on PLF age cost.xlsx",sheet_name="Age>25",index_col="Developer",usecols="Name of Project")
```

but i am getting an empty dataframe as output, however when i use

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_excel("3_Plants sorted on PLF age cost.xlsx",sheet_name="Age>25",index_col="Developer",usecols=2)
```

I get the desired result,

As i have to do it for many files using a loop and location of the columns keeps on changing so i have to go by its name and not location.

Further i cant load full file in dataframe and use `df["column_name"]`as size of my excel file is too large (150 MB) and this will make my process very slow and sometime gives memory error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that will be possible: `usecols` doesn't take Excel cell values. You could use letter column names ('A', 'B', etc...) or an `int` with the column position, but this won't be useful if the location keeps changing. My best advice would be to load only one row of the Excel file, using `nrows=1`, and figuring out the column position from there.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Tomas Farias, usecols doesn't take cell values. A possible approach is to read few rows and find the location of the column and then read the file second time.

```
import pandas as pd
col = pd.read_excel("3_Plants sorted on PLF age cost.xlsx",sheet_name="Age>25", nrows=2).columns
k=col.get_loc('Name of Project')+1
file = pd.read_excel("3_Plants sorted on PLF age cost.xlsx", sheet_name="Age>25", index_col="Developer", usecols=k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save/convert the .xlsx file to .csv and then use:
`pd.read_csv('filename.csv', usecols=[])`

Comment: U can use str or int: ex. : Pearson_Type_III=pd.read_excel(r"Log_Pearson_Type_III_Calculator.xlsx",
                   usecols=**"J:P"**, skiprows=4,engine='openpyxl',)